# Quartz Scheduler doesn't start/resume properly after database server is restarted

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, c3p0

We have a Java application that uses Quartz for scheduling jobs. The version of quartz that we use is quartz-2.2.1. The quartz configuration uses JDBC job store.

Here is the sequence of events that is happening with the system:

1. Quartz scheduler is configured via properties file and is in standby mode.
2. The database server being referred by quartz configuration is restarted as part of scheduled maintenance. It comes up in 10 min.
3. After the database is up, Quartz scheduler is started and it throws the exception that the connection is closed.

Here is the error:

```
2017-05-28 00:05:45 [WARNING] [c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
2017-05-28 00:05:45 [WARNING] [c3p0] Another error has occurred [ com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed. ] which will not be reported to listeners!
2017-05-28 00:05:45 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
2017-05-28 00:05:45     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
2017-05-28 00:05:45     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:388)
2017-05-28 00:05:45     at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.setAutoCommit(SQLServerConnection.java:1883)
2017-05-28 00:05:45     at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:1568)
2017-05-28 00:05:45     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.restoreOriginalAtributes(AttributeRestoringConnectionInvocationHandler.java:141)
2017-05-28 00:05:45     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.cleanupConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:3600)
2017-05-28 00:05:45     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3819)
2017-05-28 00:05:45     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:834)
2017-05-28 00:05:45     at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:690)
2017-05-28 00:05:45     at org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.start(QuartzScheduler.java:567)
2017-05-28 00:05:45     at org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.start(StdScheduler.java:142)
```

My question is that at the time when quartz scheduler is started, the database is up - then why it complains about that connection is already closed? I understand that it uses c3p0 connection pool internally and the application doesn't validate the connection on checkout. Does c3p0 connection pool closes the connection that is in use by the quartz scheduler (in standby mode)?

I am trying to understand the reason behind this exception and what configuration changes can be done to prevent it?

1. Shall I validate the connection on checkout in quartz properties file? Will it help here?
2. We have c3p0.properties file present in our application classpath and quartz also uses c3p0 connection pool. In that c3p0.properties file, we have set `c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout = 3600` and `c3p0.maxIdleTime = 3600`. Can this configuration lead to this issue because the time span between event #2 (when database server is restarted) and event #3 (when quartz scheduler is started) is approaximatley 1 hour (3600 seconds).

Any help shall be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should just validate the Connection on checkout, set `c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true`.

For more information on good Connection testing settings, see [c3p0's docs on the subject](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#simple_advice_on_connection_testing).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Can you help me understand how validating connection on checkout will help in mine case? In addition to it, do you think we should tune other properties like c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout = 3600 and c3p0.maxIdleTime = 3600? The min pool size is 1.

Comment: Tuning is a big question. `c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout` is only relevant if there's a bug in your application and it's leaking Connections. Validating Connections will let c3p0 realize that the Connections it acquired pre-shutdown are no longer good. then c3p0 will automatically replace them.